# Multiple scatter plot on same axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I have 3 scatter plots, was wondering how I can combine these 3 into 1 big scatter plot.

I can't seem to find a solution to this specific problem using only Matplotlib.

```
x1 = np.random.randint(40, 100, 50)
y1 = np.random.randint(40, 100, 50)

x2 = np.random.randint(0, 60, 50)
y2 = np.random.randint(0, 60, 50)

x3 = np.random.randint(40, 100, 50)
y3 = np.random.randint(0, 60, 50)

fig, (plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4) = plt.subplots(1, 4)

plot1.scatter(x1,y1, color='green', s = 10)
plot1.set(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 100))

plot2.scatter(x2,y2, color='red', s = 10)
plot2.set(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 100))

plot3.scatter(x3,y3, color='blue', s = 10)
plot3.set(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 100))

plot4.scatter(plot1, plot2, plot3)
```

so I want plot4 to be a combination of plot1, plot2 and plot3.

Answer (score 0):

Simply plot each original plot on `plot4`:

```py
plot4.scatter(x1,y1, color='green', s = 10)
plot4.scatter(x2,y2, color='red', s = 10)
plot4.scatter(x3,y3, color='blue', s = 10)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can combine each `x` and `y` array using `np.concatenate()` to call the plot command only once, but this loses the ability to color each sub-group independently.

```py
plot4.scatter(np.concatenate((x1,x2,x3)), 
              np.concatenate((y1,y2,y3)), 
              color='black', s=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the colour of the `plot4` can be different than the original ones, you can do as follows:

```
fig, (plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4) = plt.subplots(1, 4)

plot1.scatter(x1,y1, color='green', s = 10)
plot1.set(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 100))

plot2.scatter(x2,y2, color='red', s = 10)
plot2.set(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 100))

plot3.scatter(x3,y3, color='blue', s = 10)
plot3.set(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 100))

plot4.scatter([x1, x2, x3], [y1, y2, y3], color=('violet'), s = 10)
```

[image]

But if you want the colours of all the plots to be the same as they are in the three subplots, you can do what Brendan has suggested